# restart node.js application on file change

Tags: node.js

as you know in node.js if you edit a server-side file, you need to restart the application in order to make for the changes.
Now I was wondering is there a way to do this inside the server, as we know when a file has changed or not(based on last modification date), we only need to re-run the application or restart it or do something that make the changes available without us doing it from the command line.
And we all know how to do this with some [Grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/)(or something like that) or [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor), but I want to do this without any external package.
thanks alot :)

Comment: I have tried it before, the basic idea is to have a master js file which is not able to change. And it watch all the other files. Once a file change is detected, it delete the previous require cache and require the file again.

Comment: so the file cannot restart itself normally, right? there must be a master file?

Comment: I am not sure about this, sorry

Comment: no, that was plenty of help, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can initially have the server startup such that when it ends it start again. In a Bash file it would simply be a recursive function.

```
function start(){
    node index.js
    start
}
```

Or in a batch file a goto statement

```
:start
node index.js
goto start
```

Then in your node server when you detect a file change you simply end the process

For watching the files there's modules out there that make it easier. Eg. [watch](https://github.com/mikeal/watch)

```
require('watch').watchTree('./server', process.exit);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use this method to watch the files who have to restart server on change : 
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener

Comment: yes but how can I restart the server? like the code to tell the server to reset

Answer (score 0):

Using [`cluster.fork`](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) to run all code in a child process and setting the master process to fork a new child whenever the previous child exits. Then simply exit the child focibly upon file change, using [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar).

```
// Put this at the very beginning of your code
var cluster = require('cluster');
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    cluster.on('exit', cluster.fork);
    cluster.fork();
    return;
}
require('chokidar').watch('./**/*.*').on('change', process.exit);

// Rest of the code here
...
```